# How to check for local extrema or saddle point given an semidefinite matrix

Tags: analysis, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

I've computed the Hessian of a given function $f(a,b,c) = y-a\sin(bx-c)$ and got the following result:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -x\cdot\cos(bx - c) & \cos(bx - c)  \\
-x\cdot\cos(bx - c) & ax^2\cdot\sin(bx - c) & -ax\sin(bx - c) \\
\cos(bx - c) & -ax\cdot\sin(bx - c) & a\cdot\sin(bx - c)
\end{pmatrix}$

This matrix is positive semi-definite and thus one can not state for a given point $P=(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ if it is a local min, max or a saddle point. Is there any other way to explicitly determine if we have a loc. min, max or saddle point?

Comment: Would you please tell us how $f$ is defined?

Comment: oh absolutely! I apologize for missing this. I'll edit my question.

Comment: positive or negative semi definite ?

Comment: how have you determined the signature?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi, positive-semidefinite. I've set in this particular case x=4, y=3 and introduced as the point P = (1,3,2). Given x,y and P I computed the determinant for each of the leading principal minors

Comment: Ok i will edit your question

Comment: @AhmadBazzi thank you for the edit!

Comment: @Daniyal Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the given matrix, we have that

$$\det(a\sin(bx - c))=a\sin(bx - c)$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
    0 & -x\cos(bx - c)  \\
-x\cos(bx - c) & ax^2\sin(bx - c)  \\
\end{vmatrix}=-x^2\cos^2(bx - c)$$

$$\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & -x\cdot\cos(bx - c) & \cos(bx - c)  \\
   -x\cdot\cos(bx - c) & ax^2\cdot\sin(bx - c) & -ax\sin(bx - c) \\ 
\cos(bx - c) & -ax\cdot\sin(bx - c) & a\cdot\sin(bx - c)
   \end{vmatrix}=$$
$$=x\cdot\cos(bx - c)(-ax\cos(bx - c)\sin(bx - c)+ax\cos(bx - c)\sin(bx - c))+\cos(bx - c)(ax^2\cos(bx - c)\sin(bx - c)-ax^2\cos(bx - c)\sin(bx - c))=0$$

therefore for $x^2\cos^2(bx - c)\neq 0$

- $a\sin(bx - c)\le 0$ the matrix is negative semidefinite
- $a\sin(bx - c)>0$ the matrix is indefinite

and for $x^2\cos^2(bx - c)= 0$

- $a\sin(bx - c)< 0$ the matrix is negative semidefinite
- $a\sin(bx - c)>0$ the matrix is positive semidefinite

Note that the condition for critical points implies

- $f_a=-\sin(bx - c)=0\implies \sin(bx - c)=0$
- $f_b=-ax\sin(bx - c)=0\implies \sin(bx - c)=0 \lor x=0$
- $f_c=a\sin(bx - c)=0\implies \sin(bx - c)=0$

therefore

- $\cos(bx - c)=\pm 1$

and the expression for the Hessian simplifies.